# Why does binary searching take REALLY long sometimes?

Tags: java, search

I wrote two programs that create random int[] and then generate random ints to search for.  Well, really I only wrote one program, then modified the search method (like I'm supposed to for OOP, right?).  I'm using System.nanoTime() to calculate the time lapsed during search.  I get values of 10,000-13,000 consistently for the linear search, and MOSTLY times less than 5,000 for binary search(averaging in the sort time across all the searches, less than 4,000 typically for the search alone). Occasionally, though, it will through back times over 13,000, which is even longer than all but the very longest linear searches.

I have java priority set to Real Time in the task manager (Windows).  What would cause the search time to triple or more? FWIW, I get about 1 spike in linear for every 3 or 4 in binary, and the linear spike is roughly twice the normal time (22,000 was the worst so far).  Is it something with the way I've written the code?

If you don't want to read through the whole thing, in both cases I record the time in the line before calling the search method and the line after, so you can skip to the search method if you think that might be the problem. Reporting of that number is copy/pasted from one program to the other, but binary search program has more reporting that I thought would be interesting.  Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LinearSearchTimer{

public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] numbers;
    final int MAX_RUNS;
    double time1, time2, timeSpent, timeTotal;
    int searchedNumber;
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean result;
    boolean[] resultArr;
    int resultCounter;
    double pctTrue;

    MAX_RUNS = 1000;
    numbers = new int[MAX_RUNS];
    resultArr = new boolean[MAX_RUNS]; 
    resultCounter = 0;
    timeTotal = 0;


    //build array with random ints  
    for(int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++){
        numbers[k] = rand.nextInt(10001);
    }


    //generate random number and search array for it, then store to result array
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        searchedNumber = rand.nextInt(10001);
        time1 = System.nanoTime();
        result = search(numbers, searchedNumber);
        time2 = System.nanoTime();
        resultArr[resultCounter] = result;
        resultCounter++;
        timeSpent = time2 - time1;
        timeTotal += timeSpent;

    }
    pctTrue = resultPercent(resultArr);
    System.out.println("Avg time : " + timeTotal / MAX_RUNS);
    System.out.println("Percent found: " + pctTrue * 100);


}

//search algorithm, returns true if found, false if not
public static boolean search(int[] numbers, int searchedNumber){
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (found == false && i < numbers.length){
        if (numbers[i] == searchedNumber)
            found = true;
    i++;
    }
    return found;
}

public static double resultPercent(boolean[] arr){
    int trueCount = 0;
    double result;
    double runs;
    for(boolean element : arr){
        if (element == true)
            trueCount++;
    }
    runs = arr.length;//for calculating percentage as a forced double
    result = trueCount / runs;
    return result;

}

    }
```

and then...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class BinarySearchTimer{

public static void main(String[] args){

    //declare variables
    int[] numbers;
    final int MAX_RUNS;
    double time1, time2, timeSpent, timeTotal;
    int searchedNumber;
    Random rand; 
    boolean result;
    boolean[] resultArr;
    int resultCounter;
    double pctTrue;
    double timeSort1, timeSort2, timeSortSpent;

    //instantiate variables
    MAX_RUNS = 1000;
    numbers = new int[MAX_RUNS];
    resultArr = new boolean[MAX_RUNS]; 
    resultCounter = 0;
    timeTotal = 0;
    rand = new Random();


    //build array with random ints  
    for(int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++){
        numbers[k] = rand.nextInt(10001);
    }

    //sort array
    timeSort1 = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    timeSort2 = System.nanoTime();
    timeSortSpent = timeSort2 - timeSort1;


    //generate random number and call search method
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        searchedNumber = rand.nextInt(10001);

        //get start time
        time1 = System.nanoTime();
        result = search(numbers, searchedNumber, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        //get end time
        time2 = System.nanoTime();


        resultArr[resultCounter] = result;
        resultCounter++;
        timeSpent = time2 - time1;
        timeTotal += timeSpent;

    }
    pctTrue = resultPercent(resultArr);
    System.out.println("Avg time : " + timeTotal / MAX_RUNS);
    System.out.println("Percent found: " + pctTrue * 100);
    System.out.println("Actual sort time: " + timeSortSpent);
    System.out.println("Sort time shared per search: " + timeSortSpent / MAX_RUNS);
    System.out.println("Effective average search time: " + (timeTotal / MAX_RUNS + timeSortSpent / MAX_RUNS));

}

//search algorithm, returns true if found, false if not
public static boolean search(int[] numbers, int searchedNumber, int low, int high){
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    if(low > high)
        return false;
    if(numbers[mid] == searchedNumber){
        return true;
    }
    else if(searchedNumber < numbers[mid]){
        mid--;
        return search(numbers, searchedNumber, low, mid);
    }
    else if(searchedNumber > numbers[mid]){
        mid++;
        return search(numbers, searchedNumber, mid, high);
    }
    return false;
}


public static double resultPercent(boolean[] arr){
    int trueCount = 0;
    double result;
    double runs;
    for(boolean element : arr){
        if (element == true)
            trueCount++;
    }
    runs = arr.length;//for calculating percentage as a forced double
    result = trueCount / runs;
    return result;

}
```

}

Comment: a properly functioning binary search takes O(log n) worst case. if it's taking a long time, then you haven't met the requirements for a binary search (your source data **MUST** be sorted), or you've got a code bug. I'm guessing it's unsorted data. You build an array of random ints, but nowhere do you sort them into ascending order...

Comment: Units help - this is on the order of *nanoseconds*, right?  I'm just not sure if I see a problem with the performance of your sort yet.  That, and your metrics aren't exactly intuitive to follow.

Comment: @MarcB:  There's an `Arrays.sort(numbers)` call before the search loop is entered.

Comment: @Makoto: in the second code sample, not in the first one.

Comment: But the second code sample is the only code sample which uses binary search.  So I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at there.

Comment: Like @Marc said, there might be some issue with your code. I would suggest to use `Arrays.binarySearch` and compare the timings between your implementation and Java's implementation.

Comment: Now that you mention it, Makoto, I'm not sure why I included the linear search either, lol.  

vijar, I replaced the instructions in my binary search with the Arrays method, and every ten runs or so, I get a really high average number still.

Comment: Could it just be that even with Java running "real time" that something wonky with my computer is slowing down the code, and not the other way around?  I guess that would make sense, if the units are nanoseconds as Makoto suggested (actual elapsed time vs program relative time).

Comment: Makoto, I'm not likely to be a programmer once I graduate, but I'm curious about what more intuitive metrics might look like.  I'm always interested in writing cleaner, more concise programs.  Thanks.

Comment: BAHHH, looks like I build an int[] numbers with MAX_RUNS positions, then run numbers.length searches, then the divide the search time by MAX_RUNS.  In all cases, it should still be 1000, but when I changed it to the more appropriate int[1000] and use MAX_RUNS only where I'm referencing the number of tests, the problem went away and the searches got faster.  Change it back, problems reappear. Back and forth 3 times, same thing.

This is weird because the method call passes an int[], searchedNumber, low and high, none of which are directly affected by those changes.